# chrome scrolling issues after some ajax operations

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I am experiencing strange issue with scrolling, After doing some ajax operations on a webpage, which dynamically add & remove contents from the page. Mouse scrolling hangs up (*mouse scoll events doesn't work*) and pressing UP ARROW key from keyboard solves the problem.

I wonder is there any known issue like that for chrome?

**Edit:**

I don't have any js errors on the page, I am simply adding contents to div block dynamically

```
<div id="ContentArea">
    <!-- load contents here -->
</div

<script>
     loadHtml('/my/target/page', 'ContentArea');
     // this contents may vary in size
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Similar thing happened to me on `StackOverflow` when i clicked `load (n) new answers` while answering some question. (*some days ago*)

Comment: much much easier to guess if you post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had strange problems with Chrome and scrolling, then I uninstalled the [SmoothScroll](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn) extension and everything worked.

Try disabling all of your extensions and see if the problem persists (note: disabling does not uninstall them but will help you identify if an extension is causing the problem):

Menu button -> Tools -> Extensions

Then click the Disable link on all of them (and you may want to restart Chrome for good measure)

Comment: I have bunch of other extensions installed, may be one of them is causing it. So i should not worry if its only on my browser.

Comment: I'm having this problem on my machine without smoothscroll

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues and got them fixed by scrolling to the top/left corner before replacing the content. Just add the following line before you replace anything:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

I've tested it only with Chromium 9.0.594.0 (67311) on Mac, but I think chances are good that this will work with on other platforms as well.

Comment: This did it for me: window.scrollTo(window.scrollTop()+1);